# How To Set A JS object property name from a variable

Tags: javascript

I am in need to set a JS object property name dynamically.

```
for(i=1; i<3; i++) {
    var key  = i+'name';

    data = {
        key : 'name1',
    }
}
```

Result should be:

```
data = {
    1name: 'name1'
    2name: 'name1'
}
```

Comment: If they are sequential, why are you not using an Array?

Comment: I want to know which three of you hit the wrong arrow.  C'mon, fess up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 210, accepted):

```
var jsonVariable = {};
for(var i=1; i < 3; i++) {
  jsonVariable[i + 'name'] = 'name' + i;        
}
```

Comment: Musa's response below also correctly articulates that using [] notation is actually the only way to do it.

Comment: Also note that @ChilNut's response below now describes the easiest way of doing this using ES6

Comment: Actually, with the new syntax what OP is trying to achieve will only be possible if the loop limit is hardcoded and small.

Answer (score 218):

You'll have to use `[]` notation to set keys dynamically.

```
var jsonVariable = {};
for(i=1; i<3; i++) {        
 var jsonKey  = i+'name';
 jsonVariable[jsonKey] = 'name1';

}
```

Now in ES6 you can use object literal syntax to create object keys dynamically, just wrap the variable in `[]`

```
var key  = i + 'name';
data = {
    [key] : 'name1',
}
```

Comment: jsonVariable = {}; should not be initialized inside the for loop.

Comment: Also you're making jsonVariable global here

Answer (score 146):

With ES 6, you can use variable property names with the object literal syntax, like this:

```
var keyName = 'myKey';
var obj = {
              [keyName]: 1
          };
obj.myKey;//1
```

This syntax is available in the following newer browsers:

> Edge 12+ (No IE support), FF34+, Chrome 44+, Opera 31+, Safari 7.1+

(https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

You can add support to older browsers by using a [transpiler](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-transpilers-what-they-are-why-we-need-them) such as [babel](https://babeljs.io/). It is easy to transpile an entire project if you are using a module bundler such as [rollup](http://rollupjs.org/guide/) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/).

Comment: Without ES6 I can't define  var payload={dynamicKey:val} , I need to do var payload={} and payload[variableName]=val.

Answer (score 42):

**Use a variable as an object key**

```
let key = 'myKey';

let data = {[key] : 'name1'; }
```

See [How to iterete on your object here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more to let others know why this might be a solution?

Comment: The info you added are fine, just never give an answer with just code ;)

Answer (score 22):

This is the way to dynamically set the value

```
var jsonVariable = {};
for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    var jsonKey = i + 'name';
    jsonVariable[jsonKey] = 'name' + i;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It does not matter where the variable comes from. Main thing we have one ...
Set the variable name between square brackets "[ .. ]".

```
var optionName = 'nameA';
var JsonVar = {
[optionName] : 'some value'
}
```

Comment: This works nice, I wonder if it works in all browsers / versions

Answer (score 1):

```
jsonVariable = {}
for(i=1; i<3; i++) {        
   var jsonKey  = i+'name';
   jsonVariable[jsonKey] = 'name1'
}
```

this will be similar to

```
    jsonVariable = {
    1name : 'name1'
    2name : 'name1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of Sainath S.R's comment above, I was able to set a js object property name from a variable in Google Apps Script (which does not support ES6 yet) by defining the object then defining another key/value outside of the object:

```
var salesperson = ...

var mailchimpInterests = { 
        "aGroupId": true,
    };

mailchimpInterests[salesperson] = true;
```