# <%= %> variable syntax in Gruntfile throws "unable to read"

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gruntfile

I'm using the following in my Gruntfile:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    assets: grunt.option('assets'),
    config: grunt.file.readJSON(path.join('<%= assets %>', 'config.json')) || grunt.file.readJSON('./defaults.json'),
    ...
})
```

When I execute it, it throws:

```
>> Error: Unable to read "<%= assets %>/config.json" file (Error code: ENOENT).
    >> at Object.util.error (/.../prj/node_modules/grunt-legacy-util/index.js:54:39)
    >> at Object.file.read (/.../prj/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js:247:22)
    >> at Object.file.readJSON (/.../prj/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js:253:18)
    >> at Object.module.exports (/.../prj/Gruntfile.js:10:28)
    >> at loadTask (/.../prj/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:325:10)
    >> at Task.task.init (/.../prj/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:437:5)
    >> at Object.grunt.tasks (/.../prj/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:120:8)
    >> at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/.../prj/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:38:9)
    >> at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:45:20)
    >> at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
```

Wondering if this is because the `assets` var isn't defined at the point I'm trying to use it? Or is the <%= %> syntax not allowed to be used in this fashion?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21635353/1214800), it looks like it should work -- which I found because previously I was just using `var assets = grunt.option('assets')`, but *that* was throwing `SyntaxError: Unexpected token var` for some reason. (Before I messed with it, it looked like this:)

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt)

    var util = require('util'),
        path = require('path'),
        pkg = require('./package.json')

    var assets = grunt.option('assets'),
    var config = grunt.file.readJSON(path.join(assets, 'config.json')) || grunt.file.readJSON('./defaults.json')

    grunt.initConfig({
        ...
    })
```

**What's the proper, grunt way of using a module or declaring a variable inside a gruntfile like this? And/or, can I fix the problem with `Unexpected token var`?**

(*Note:* It's not the config file that I'm having trouble loading, it's the fact that the assets path from `grunt.option()` appears to not be interpreted)

Comment: Who-ever down voted it, please state your reason.  Its a perfectly valid programming question +1.

Comment: You have a extra comma after `var assets = grunt.option('assets')` ,. Either remove that or remove the var in next line

Comment: Keeping this open to award points, but did my solemn duty and voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to read a custom json file. Remember that even grunt script is just JavaScript and node requires work just fine. So you can do something like

```
 var conf = grunt.file.exists(assets + '/ '+ 'config.json') ? require(assets + '/ '+ 'config.json') : {};
```

You can then use your `config` variable around where ever.

```
conf.foo || 'default'
conf.bar
```

In either case you need to declare `assets` variable before usage. In require or in `initConfig`

> Update

Also,
You have a extra comma after `var assets = grunt.option('assets'),` Either remove that or remove the `var` in next line

Comment: The config file loads fine; it's `grunt.option('assets')` that it's breaking on I think

Comment: where do you define `assets` then? is it a variable or a parameter?

Comment: Originally I had it as `var assets = grunt.option('assets')`. Then it started gawking at me about using `var` inside the gruntfile, so I switched to trying to use `assets: grunt.option('assets')` to load the arg, so that `assets` becomes a grunt variable.

Comment: I see. Okay try without using path.join().  Try joining the string yourself using asset to see if it works, something like `config: grunt.file.readJSON('<%= assets %>/'config.json')`

Comment: Hrm, nope even that doesn't work. Probably can't use it at all like this -- like what @ahmadbamieh's answer states.

Comment: right.. so you can only use it in simple key value pairs. In my grunt files, I just load the configs like I showed using a regular require. It should be a valid json file though.

Comment: See my edit to the question - originally I was using `var assets = grunt.option('assets')` and it was working just fine. Now it's not though - throwing the `Invalid token var` error.

Comment: You have a extra comma after `var assets = grunt.option('assets'),`. Either remove that or remove the `var` in next line

Comment: FACEPALM. Nice catch. Unbelievable. Edit your answer with that at the top, I'll accept.

Comment: ha ha.. Happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare `var assets = ..` inside the `grunt.init( {` Curly braces, as that is not valid JS syntax. What you need to do in order for it to understand the `<%= %>` syntax is declare it like so:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
        options: {
            banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %>'
            // pkg is a property on the json object passed into initConfig
...
```

Comment: if you declare the assets variable before the initCongfig, you could do `pkg: assets,`. Not sure what your doing with _grunt.option()_

Comment: Not sure how that's different from what I'm doing exactly? Other than that your example reads a json file, and mine is loading a command line arg?

Answer (score 0):

The `<%= %>` is an interpolation string specified by grunt, if you use it in non-grunt parameters, it will not be interpolated (such as your case in using it in path.join).

to make it work you have to use

```
grunt.template.process('<%= asset %>', {
   data: {
      assets: grunt.option('assets')
   }
})
```

Comment: Alright, that explains why the interpolation syntax isn't working. Any idea why my original way using `var` would no longer be working?

Comment: yes, the interpolation takes from 'this' which is the object itself, hence in order to get the value of var, you have to put it in the object of `initConfig` such as `initConfig({assets: assets, //...}`