# Creating an object with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript

Here is a function building an object dynamically:

```
function onEntry(key, value) {
  console.log(key) // productName
  console.log(value) // Budweiser

  const obj = { key: value }
  console.log(obj) // { key: "Budweiser" }
}
```

Expected output is

```
{ productName: "Budweiser" }
```

But property name is not evaluated

```
{ key: "Budweiser" }
```

How to make property name of an object **evaluated as an expression**?

Comment: ` var tmp = {};tmp[k]=v;`

Comment: You should use bracket notation as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833204/how-to-set-a-js-object-property-name-from-a-variable).

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an object, and set its key manually.

```
var obj = {}
obj[key] = value
```

Or using [ECMAScript 2015](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) syntax, you can also do it directly in the object declaration:

```
var obj = {
  [key] = value
}
```