# jQuery using variable to fill in property value

Tags: jquery, css

I am attempting use a variable to fill in the property value of this CSS jQuery code.  In the example below I am using an array to try to fill it in but it is giving me an error.  I've attempted this without using it as an array where "tops" equaled "bottom" but still nothing.

```
var tops = [ '"top"', '"bottom"' ];
$(div).css({ tops[1] : 5 });
```

Comment: `$('div')` not `$(div)`. `div` is not a variable

Comment: Can you make use of ECMAScript 6, if so http://stackoverflow.com/a/30927533/2539720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an expression as the literal key of an object. You need to use the singular setter of jQuery's `css()` method:

```
var tops = [ 'top', 'bottom' ]; // note only a single set of quotes around the values
$(div).css(tops[1], 5);
```

This is also assuming the `div` variable holds a DOMElement. If you want to select all `div` elements in the DOM, use a string selector: `$('div')`.

Comment: Nice.  That worked perfectly.  This was my end results

var tops = ['top', 'bottom'];
$(this).css(tops[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)], Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1);

Comment: Glad to help. Note that you can make the first part less rigid by reading the `length` property of the array: `tops[Math.floor(Math.random() * tops.length)]`