# DynamoDB batchwriteItem don't put data to dynamic TableName in Lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to write data to different tables, tablename is passed through get request.

```
var tableName = event.tableName.toString();
```

When I write hardcoded tableName it works fine but when I write variable Name it throws error.

2018-11-20T21:09:31.532Z    928e237c-ed08-11e8-a312-539d290e67fc    {"errorMessage":"Requested resource not found","errorType":"ResourceNotFoundException","stackTrace":["Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)","Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)","Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)","Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)","Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)","AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)","/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10","Request. (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)","Request. (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)","Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)"]}
END RequestId: 928e237c-ed08-11e8-a312-539d290e67fc
REPORT RequestId: 928e237c-ed08-11e8-a312-539d290e67fc  Duration: 124.41 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms     Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 33 MB

Here is the code:

```
var params = {
RequestItems: {
    tableName :  [
   {
     PutRequest: {
        "Item" : {
        "indexNumber":{
            "N": r1index
        },
         "DateandTime" :{
          "S": DnT1  
        } ,
        "roadId" :{
          "N": id
        },
        "x1_axis":{
           "S": x11
        },
        "y1_axis":{
            "S":  y11
        },
        "z1_axis":{
            "S": z11
        },
        "x2_axis":{
           "S": x21
        },
        "y2_axis":{
            "S":  y21
        },
        "z2_axis":{
            "S": z21
        },
        "latitude":{
            "S": lat1
        },
        "longitude":{
            "S":lng1
        }
    }
     }
   },
   {
     PutRequest: {
        "Item" : {
        "indexNumber":{
            "N": r2index
        },
        "DateandTime" :{
          "S": DnT2 
      } ,
        "roadId" :{
          "N": id
        },
        "x1_axis":{
           "S": x12
        },

        "y1_axis":{
            "S":  y12
        },
        "z1_axis":{
            "S": z12
        },
        "x2_axis":{
           "S": x22
        },
        "y2_axis":{
            "S":  y22
        },
        "z2_axis":{
            "S": z22
        },
        "latitude":{
            "S": lat2
        },
        "longitude":{
            "S":lng2
        }
    }
     }
   },
          {
     PutRequest: {
       "Item" : {
        "indexNumber":{
            "N": r3index
        },
        "DateandTime" :{
          "S": DnT3  
        } ,
         "roadId" :{
          "N": id
        },
        "x1_axis":{
           "S": x13
        },
        "y1_axis":{
            "S":  y13
        },
        "z1_axis":{
            "S": z13
        },
        "x2_axis":{
           "S": x23
        },
        "y2_axis":{
            "S":  y23
        },
        "z2_axis":{
            "S": z23
        },
        "latitude":{
            "S": lat3
        },
        "longitude":{
            "S":lng3
        }
    }
     }
   }
]
```

}
    };

Comment: please add information how do you concatenate string to place `tableName` in final code. Also add to your code  `console.log(JSON.stringify(event));` to check what event contains

Comment: I am passing table name from get request. And I get it in console.log(); even table is present and region is also the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your json is incorrect.  When you define your RequestItems object like

```
RequestItems: { tableName: [...] }
```

you actually are hard-coding the string "tableName" as the attribute, not a variable called "tableName".  This is why there's no table called that.

The es6 solution is to do this:

```
RequestItems: { [tableName]: [...] }
```

The old-fashioned solution is to do this:

```
var RequestItems = {};
RequestItems[tableName] = [...];
```

See [How To Set A JS object property name from a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833204/how-to-set-a-js-object-property-name-from-a-variable) for reference

Edit:

For a more complete solution, try:

```
var params = {};
params.RequestItems = {};
params.RequestItems[tableName] = [...]
```

Comment: THANKS FOR REPLAY, but the problem still exists

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'unitest' of undefined
    at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:181:32)
where tableName='unitest';

Comment: I am doing it like
var params  = {};
var RequestItems =  {};
params.RequestItems[tableName] = [ 
       {...}
];

Comment: Still an issue with your json.  params.RequestItems creates a new attribute for the params object (it's not using the variable you defined)